# String javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression.evaluate(Object item) guarantees it never returns null in all implementations?

Tags: java, xpath-api

From the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate(java.lang.Object)): returns: The String that is the result of evaluating the expression and converting the result to a String.

```
/**
 * ...
 * ...
 * @return The <code>String</code> that is the result of evaluating the expression and converting the result to a 
 *   <code>String</code>.
 * ...
 * ...
 */
String javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression.evaluate(Object item)
```

The question is, it is a bit vauge what is the contract here in case the expression finds nothing. Is null an valid / invalid return in all implementations? where is the return API defined? in the JSR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there is no such thing as null in XPath. My guess would be it returns the empty string.

**Update:** a quick look at [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) and [XPath 2.0 Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/) specs confirms this feeling.

Comment: Makes sense, but is it documented somewhere? is there an official guidline to the implementers of this API to avoid returning null? and is there a link to it?

And if so, then how would one differ between "your xpath found a node, and it contained the value 'empty string'" to "your xpath didn't find anything"? (I guess that for this you have the evaluate that returns an object)

Comment: If you don't find anything, the XPath returns the empty sequence, which is converted to the empty string (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string)

Comment: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression.evaluate(Object item, QName returnType) returns null if it doesn't find anything by the way

Answer (score 1):

This could be not an expected answer.

```xml
<types>
    <type id="1">
        <href>aaa</href>
    </type>
</types>
```

Lets say you wrote a method finds `@id` by `href`.

```
Double findIdByHref(final String href) {
    evaluate("/:types/:type[:href='bbb']/@id", NUMBER);
}
```

This method returns `0` not `null` for `bbb` as href

```
final Double id = findByHref("bbb"); // not null
```

I had to modify like this

```
Double findIdByHref(final String href) {
    final Node node = evaluate("/:types/:type[:href='bbb']", NODE);
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return evaluate("@id", node);
}
```